# Android calculate angle between 2 GPS coordinates

Tags: java, android, gps

I'm developing an application where I show the user's movements on a map using GPS coordinates. Calculating the size of the movement between two location with loc1.distanceTo (loc2), where loc1 and 2 are of type Location. How can I calculate the angle (in degrees) of the movement?

Comment: Do you mean to calculate the slope.

Comment: I want to calculate how many degrees the 2nd target is rotated relative to the first

Answer (score 3):

Did you do a search before you asked? This has been answered several times before. You can get the bearing (which I guess is what you mean by angle) through [Location.bearingTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo%28android.location.Location%29). In your case it would be:

```
loc1.bearingTo(loc2)
```

Comment: But the angle is relative to the first location or to an x or y axis? what is the reference point?

Comment: the reference is geographical north, and the start point (loc1)

Comment: I supose that loc1 is in the center of the goniometric circunference and i need to find the angle of the movement of loc2